# Different behaviour of timedelta vs relativedelta when added to NaT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

The below behaviour is a bit surprising where adding `NaT` to `timedelta` works gracefully while doing so with `relativedelta` doesn't. Is it really an outcome of word `relative`?

```
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(np.nan) + timedelta(days=1)
NaT

pd.to_datetime(np.nan) + relativedelta(days=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_8.1.0.202012051215\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py", line 405, in __radd__
    return self.__add__(other)
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dateutil\relativedelta.py", line 377, in __add__
day = min(calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1],
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\calendar.py", line 124, in monthrange
raise IllegalMonthError(month)
calendar.IllegalMonthError: bad month number nan; must be 1-12
```

Comment: what do you mean by "*outcome of word relative*"? timedelta and relativedelta are different classes, although it may sound like they are related. So I'd *not* expect identical behavior.

Comment: Could relativedelta be processing the timestamp relative to which it's trying to create delta? 
Is the above behaviour difference expected? If so, then why?

Comment: I think relativedelta lacks a definition (method) what do do with pd.NaT (it's pandas-specific, there's no NaT in standard lib datetime). In general, if you work with pandas, I'd suggest to use the pandas built-ins; e.g. instead of relativedelta use DateOffset; `pd.NaT + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)` - that also works fine, giving NaT. So I don't see a need for relativedelta to implement pd.NaT handling.

Comment: @GregoirePelegrin arithmetic involving NaN (or NaT) is not uncommon. Adding (or subtracting) anything to/from NaN / NaT *should* give NaN, this is the result I would expect.